# A term to be in the same position

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiom-request

A term to act in the same way

> You are you; I am I,
>   Neither I nor you're less,
>   We're to obey friend's friendship.
>   O my darling, tipple, o My sweetheart tipple.

The passage above is a translation of :

> तुम तुम हो; हम हम हैं.
>   ना तुम कम हो न हम कम हैं.
>   यार की है यारी निभानी.
>   पीले पीले वो मोरे राजा.
>   पीले वो मोरे जानी.

That's from a Hindi movie. In this song two friends say that their position is the same by using 'less’ कम:

> **Neither I nor you're less**

I want to know that *less* here works be in the same position or acting in the same way – if it does not, provide some idioms

Comment: Note that the contracted form doesn’t work here. The sentence should say, “Neither I nor **you are** less,” and not, “Neither I nor _you’re_ less.” (Other than than, the word _less_ works fine in that way.)

Comment: I think '**_less_**', in this context, means _'to be considered in a lower standard than the other'_.

Comment: I would suggest **the lesser** (and I agree with J.R. about the unnaturalness of the contracted "you're" in this **Neither I nor you** structure.)

Comment: Is "tipple" an imperative verb in the original? Does it mean "let's drink to that!" ?

Comment: @ TRomano, yes !

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to say that neither person is the superior or the inferior is

> We're equals.